# how to check if input field is empty

Tags: jquery

I'm making a form with inputs, if the input type is empty then the button submit is disabled but, if the input fields is with length > 0 the submit button is enabled

```
<input type='text' id='spa' onkeyup='check()'><br>
<input type='text' id='eng' onkeyup='check()'><br>
<input type='button' id='submit' disabled>

function check() {
  if($("#spa").lenght>0 && $("#eng").lenght>0) {
    $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
  }
}
```

it works but if then I delete for example the content of input spa the button submit is still enabled

Comment: length != lenght

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use trim and val.

```
var value=$.trim($("#spa").val());

if(value.length>0)
{
 //do some stuffs. 
}
```

`val()` : return the value of the input.

`trim()`: will trim the white spaces.

Answer (score 19):

use `.val()`, it will return the value of the `<input>`

```
$("#spa").val().length > 0
```

And  you had a typo, `length` not `lenght`.

Answer (score 7):

As javascript is dynamically typed, rather than using the .length property as above you can simply treat the input value as a boolean:

```
var input = $.trim($("#spa").val());

if (input) {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

You can also extract the logic out into functions, then by assigning a class and using the `each()` method the code is more dynamic if, for example, in the future you wanted to add another input you wouldn't need to change any code.

So rather than hard coding the function call into the input markup, you can give the inputs a class, in this example it's `test`, and use:

```
$(".test").each(function () {
    $(this).keyup(function () {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", CheckInputs());
    });
});
```

which would then call the following and return a boolean value to assign to the `disabled` property:

```
function CheckInputs() {
    var valid = false;
    $(".test").each(function () {
        if (valid) { return valid; }
        valid = !$.trim($(this).val());
    });
    return valid;
}
```

You can see a working example of everything I've mentioned in [this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/NAXE2/)

Answer (score 4):

Why don't u use:

```
<script>
$('input').keyup(function(){
if(($('#eng').val().length > 0) && ($('#spa').val().length > 0))
    $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
else
    $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
});
</script>
```

Then delete the onkeyup function on the input.

Comment: `$('#eng,#spa')` rather than `$('input')`, i'd say. and make sure to run the script on DOMReady.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$.trim($("#spa").val()).length > 0
```

It will not treat any white space if any as a correct value

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `jquery-validate.js` in your application then use below expression.

```
if($("#spa").is(":blank"))
{
  //code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This snippet will handle more than two checkboxes in case you decide to expand the form.

```
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function(){
    var count = 0, attr = "disabled", $sub = $("#submit"), $inputs = $("input[type=text]");  
    $inputs.each(function(){
        count += ($.trim($(this).val())) ? 1:0;
    });
    (count >= $inputs.length ) ? $sub.removeAttr(attr):$sub.attr(attr,attr);       
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/sr4gq/

Comment: Though if the page had another text input, a search field for example, this code would break so a class would be less brittle. Using an integer to set a boolean doesn't really make syntactic sense either so other developers may be confused by your code.

Comment: @Pete Uh I agree, at that point it would be best to move to a class based selector as you suggest, however I do not see where I"m using an integer to set a boolean, are you talking about using the falsey characteristics of an empty string?

Comment: sorry if I was vague, I am referring to the use of a count to check the number of inputs with a value, and then comparing that integer with a count of all of the inputs. If you see my example I am using a boolean to set the `disabled` property instead which I believe is more syntactically correct.