# Remove functionality in text Filed not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, textfield, keyup

We are developing a PhoneGap app. We have 3 cases like this:

```
$("#dvData .quantity input").on('keyup', function() {
    var totalamount = 0;
    var discountAmount = 0;
    var LineAmount1 = 0;
    var vatAmount = 0;
    var FinalNetSales = 0;
    var qtyId = this.id;
    var qtyId1 = qtyId.substr(4);
    debugger;
    var sstextFieldvalue = $('#text' + qtyId1).val();

    alert(sstextFieldvalue);
    alert(sstextFieldvalue.length);

    if (sstextFieldvalue != "" || sstextFieldvalue != 0) {
        if (sstextFieldvalue > 20) {
            alert("Set1");
        } else {
            alert("FINE");
        }
    } 
    else {
        alert("REMOVE");
    }
});
```

When we enter more then 20 in text-field it's called first alert. If we enter a value in text-field it is called three alert. However, when we remove text-field value it's not call Second alert.

Please tell me what is wrong in my code.

Note: This code is working fine in browser but when we checked in my mobile devices it not working

Answer (score 0):

use `else if(sstextFieldvalue.length == "")` instead of `else if(! sstextFieldvalue)`

```
else if(sstextFieldvalue == "")
```

Ok, i found this: [how to check if input field is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268236/how-to-check-if-input-field-is-empty), so you can test the `length` of `sstextFieldvalue`.

**update**
Your problem is your test, you can try this, tested on mobile:

```
if(sstextFieldvalue!="" || sstextFieldvalue!=0){
    if(sstextFieldvalue.length>20){
        alert("Set1");
    } else {
        alert("FINE");
    }
} else {
    alert("REMOVE");
}
```

**Explain**

1.It test if `sstextFieldvalue!="" || sstextFieldvalue!=0`, if it's true, it test if `sstextFieldvalue.length>20` and show `alert("Set1")`, else it shows `alert("FINE");`

2. into `else`, it means that the field is empty.

Hope it works for you as well as it works for me! :)

Comment: shouldn't that evaluate to be false?

Comment: Yeah, but in his case, he should test if the field is empty or not! :)

Comment: @Radonirina Maminiaina else if(sstextFieldvalue == ""); this also working fine in web but when we check mobile it's not work for me

Comment: so what happen if test the length of the field value?

Comment: @Radonirina Maminiaina  yes we tried  else if(sstextFieldvalue.length = 0); also but not working in mobile .it working in browser Please help me

Comment: you did `if(sstextFieldvalue.length == 0);` or `if(sstextFieldvalue.length = 0);`?

Comment: @Radonirina Maminiaina sry we tried sstextFieldvalue.length == 0 not sstextFieldvalue.length = 0

Comment: @Radonirina Maminiaina thanks we will try as you said

Comment: @Radonirina Maminiaina We tried as you said same line placed in my code but it's not working.it working fine in browser but when we used mobile we removed textField value using backspaces "REMOVE " alert not called

Comment: what event you use? I use `keyup` on my test and it runs

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina yes we used Keyup event so Please look my question once we add event

Comment: You do `sstextFieldvalue>20` instead of `sstextFieldvalue.length>20`, and dicrease, for e.g 3, the number, so it will be ease to you to do the test. I tested on my phone and it works perfecty! :)